# CSS force child element to fit into parent element

Tags: css, height, overflow

How do I force a child element to fit into the parent, i.e. show the scroll bar on #content?

http://jsfiddle.net/vzaVc/

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="header">
        varied-sized header
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        the real content<br>
        this can be so long<br>
        that it doesn't fit into the parent<br>
        so this should get a scroll bar<br>
        so that the user can... scroll it down<br>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}
#header {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 20px;
}
#content {
    background-color: green;    
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}​
```

**EDIT:**

Can I get away without specifying the height on the #content? Computing the right value of that property might be difficult and cumbersome (if other things change).

Answer (score 2):

If you want `#content` to have a scroll bar, add a CSS `height` attribute and `overflow`, e.g.

```
height: 160px;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: 1. What if I don't want/can't use absolute height but need relative instead (e.g. 100%) 2. what if the parent element is defeind with style="box-sizing: border-box;" ?

Comment: Why does everything in CSS have to be a fixed size. I don't like the HTML layout system. It is so brittle.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the `#parent` CSS:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

or add it to the child's CSS if you want the child to have a scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you *always* want to show the scrollbar, the answer is -- as mentioned in the other response -- adding `overflow-y: scroll;`to the CSS.

If however, you only want to show the scrollbar if the content gets too big, the answer is to set an absolute height, and use `overflow-y:auto;`:

```
height: 180px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

An important thing to note is that if the overflow-x and overflow-y do not match, the default that gets applied is auto. So if you have `overflow-x: hidden` and `overflow-y: visible`, the browser will interpret this as `overflow: auto`.  Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: OK, but can I get away without specifying the height?

Comment: @Stefan -- Yes, but you may instead specify `max-height`. What these two heights indicate is the size beyond which the scrollbar should be displayed. `max-height` would say "this box can be any height up to this specified *x*, beyond which show a scrollbar", while just `height` indicates that the box is always that specific height and the scrollbar is just to be added if the content grows beyond that.

Comment: Essentially, if you always want the scrollbar visible, regardless of how much content there is, you can get away without specifying the height or a maximum height (and use `overflow-y: scroll`.) But if you only want to show a scrollbar if the content overflows its container (using `overflow-y: auto`), you need to specify the height (or maximum height) of that container.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the edit, I usually specify the height of the child object as a percentage, which makes it a percentage of the parent element's height.

```
height: 80%;
top: 15%;
```

This would make it always be 80% of the parent object's height, have a 5% margin from the bottom, and a 15% margin from the top where your header could fit.